# How can I edit an object without saved it in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

There is a problem with my Django project, when I add an object it saves immediatly after that I will be redirected by object id to **server_edit** where I can fill fields. If I fill no fields and push "back" (go to previous page) browser button object will be saved without any data even if **Save** button was not pushed on template.

Is there any way do not save object where no fields was filled?

How can I edit an object without saved it?

I have a model "Server" that contains a few CharField

```
class Server(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
```

I add and save an object:

```
def server_add(request):
    server = Server()
    server.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('server:server_edit', args=(server.id,)))
```

after this I redirect to edit page:

```
def server_edit(request, server_id):
    server = get_object_or_404(Server, pk=server_id)
    return render(request, 'server/server_edit.html'{'server': server})
```

Fields will be edited on html template:

```
<form action="{% url 'server:server_edit_post' server.id %}"  method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
    <tr>
        <td>{% trans "Name:" %}</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="name" maxlength="256" value="{{server.name}}" required></td>
    </tr>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">{% trans "Save" %}</button>
</form>
```

This view gets data from the template and allows to edit them:

```
def server_edit_post(request, server_id):
    server= get_object_or_404(Server, pk=server_id)
    name = request.POST['name']
    server.name = name
    server.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('server:server_index', args=()))
```

Comment: This may be too broad to answer but can you explain why you want to store that object in first place ?

Comment: Because I have to have object id (pk) to use the same object in server_edit. This is the arg for HttpResponseRedirect.

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid saving object and **then** filling it with data in different view.

Try using generic edit views such as CreateView/EditView or FormView with Django forms (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/).

Example:

```
class ServerCreateView(CreateView):
    form_class = ServerCreateForm
    template_name = 'servers/add.html'
```

With this, all validation is done automatically.

Comment: - "Is there any way do not save object where no fields was filled?"
- Yes, do it properly and use Django's editing views which validate fields automatically and will return error when field was send empty.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I would like to avoid using Django forms, but if there is no another way - ok.

Answer (score 0):

Http calls should be stateless. The connection can be dropped any time, which leaves the DB in the same inconsistent state which is what you try to avoid here. Instead of using the form which only contains name, you could just redirect the user to a new page with the form for the rest of the data with the previously entered name as a get parameter, and pre-fill that form with the name on that page